# Previous Column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this formula to apply conditional formatting to a cell in a range if the previous two cells in the row are blank.

```
=AND(WEEKNUM(TODAY())=RIGHT(D$2,2),ISBLANK(B3),ISBLANK(C3))
```

The range is this

```
=$D$3:$AL$27
```

Row two has the week number.  The cell fill should be red if the two previous cells are blank (no data entered for the previous two weeks).  This formula does not seem to do this.

Comment: How is D2 formatted? What values D2 holds? If D2 just holds a Weeknumber then remove the RIGHT function and make a direct comparison between the 2 numbers, the one in D2 and one returned by TODAY, else wrap RIGHT function in VALUE function to essentially return a number from RIGHT function and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  The problem was that I was comparing a number to a text.  IF I put WEEKNUM in a TEXT function everything works.  This is the formula that worked.

```
=AND(TEXT(WEEKNUM(TODAY()),"00")=RIGHT(F$3,2),ISBLANK(D4),ISBLANK(E4))
```